# Increase spacing after footnotes' rule/line?

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, rules

I know you can increase the spacing between the main text and the footnotes' line/ruler with

```
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{}
```

So I wonder if there's a command to increase the space between the line/ruler and the footnotes.

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: You can adjust by altering `\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@%
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@} % %here change the value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I add `20pt` vertically after the footnoterule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\svfootnoterule\vspace{20pt}}
\begin{document}
x\footnote{pdq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!